# How to Retrieve All Tables From SQL Database (Excluding System Tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

### Goal

To retrieve all tables from SQL Database while excluding the system tables.

[image: Table retrieval]

The tables in green notify the ones I want and the red rectangle are the ones I want to exclude (system tables)

---

### Attempt

Here's what I tried

```
Private Function GetTables(ByVal cnSql As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim lst_Tables As New List(Of String)
    Dim mycn As SqlConnection
    Dim myCmd As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim myData As New DataSet()

    mycn = New SqlConnection(cnSql) 'Properly connects to my database
    mycn.Open()
    myCmd = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables ORDER BY TABLE_NAME", mycn)
    myCmd.Fill(myData)
    mycn.Close()

    For Each table As DataTable In myData.Tables
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            'Only fetch tables (ommit views)
            If row.ItemArray(3).ToString = "BASE TABLE" Then
                For Each col As DataColumn In table.Columns
                    If col.ToString() = "TABLE_NAME" Then
                        lst_Tables.Add(row(col).ToString())
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Return lst_Tables
End Function
```

Unfortunately, this also returns the System Tables ... How would I go about not including these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query instead of yours:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
```

You can also use the `is_ms_shipped = 0` in your predicate.

Comment: Yup, was about to post `SELECT [name] as tablename FROM sysObjects WHERE (type = 'U')`.

Comment: This still returns the two system tables mentioned in the screenshot above.

Comment: That can't be true, or you have corrupted sql server.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Well, the SQL Server is in 2005 ... maybe that has something to do with it? Because I don't think the SQL server is corrupted.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan You're right, at first I tested in 2008 but then in 2005. In any case, this helped. I shall accept the answer with an upvote. Thank you for your help!